# Getting data from a server and adding it to a local variable for future use in json

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch or get data from a url and save it into a variable for future use.How to do that?Using nodejs and angular.The code is

```
let dataarray = [];
const request = require('request');
//url:http://localhost:5000/data/
request({ url: url, json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
//console.log(body);
dataarray[0] = push(body);
})

sort(dataarray[]);//or any other functionalities and the displaying it to angular.
```

Comment: Try `dataarray.push(body)`

Comment: I think you need to study a course on this.

Comment: dataarray.push(body) -prints and empty array.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, you can try using HTTP Client. I created a service called `user-management-db.service.ts` which handles making http calls to my nodeJS cloud functions.

In this service class I have a function called `getAllUsers()` which just returns an array of firebase users when called

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpClient,
    HttpHeaders,
    HttpParams,
    HttpEventType
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';

//data model
import { AFUser } from '../data models/AFUser.model';

@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root' })

export class UserManagementDBService {
    APIPath: string = 'http://localhost:5000/api/users'

    // constructor( private db: AngularFirestore) { }
    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    }
    //get all users
    getAllUsers() {
    //return observable containing an array of users
    //parse the json respone into the trial meeting object
    return this.http.get<AFUser>(`${this.APIPath}`)
        //pipe the data to do any manipulations
        .pipe(
            /*
                This request returns an array of nested users with matching db records
                Therefore it needs to be mapped twice to get the nested user object to then be built up into an array
                users": [
                        {
                            "user": {
                                "uid": "",
                                "email": "",
                                "displayName": "",
                                "role": "",
                                "lastSignInTime": "",
                                "creationTime": ""
                            },
                            "db": {
                            }
            */
        //map the response error
        map(responseData => {
            //map the root level array json key 'users'
            return responseData['users'].map(item => {
                //create an user using the next level json key
                //combine these into a array of users to be returned to the calling funciton
                return <AFUser[]>item
            })
        }),
        //catch any errors that may arise while fetching
        catchError(errorResponse => {
            return throwError(errorResponse)
        })
        )
    }
}
```

I then subscribe to this service in an component and call it like so:

```js
loadTableData() {
    //subscribe to getAllUsers() method
    this.databaseService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => {
        console.log(users);
        //THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN STORE THE RETURNED ARRAY FROM HTTP INTO ANOTHER VARIABLE
        //set the datasource for table to the user array that is returned
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
        //hide the spinner
        this.showSpinner = false;
            //set up row sort
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }, error => {
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.snack.notification("Error Fetching Users", "OK")
    })
}
```

I recommend you follow this Udemy course which has helped me to learn more about Angular: [Angular - The Complete Guide (2021 Edition)](https://www.udemy.com/share/101WgAAEQfcV1XQXw=/)